# Name for a closed shape that has an interior point such that every line through the point meets the shape's boundary at exactly $k$ distinct points?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, convex-analysis, polygons, convex-geometry

Consider a closed shape/set $S \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that there exists an interior point $(x, y) \in S$ (need not be unique) such that any line passing through $(x, y)$ intersects $S$'s boundary at exactly $k$ distinct points.

> Is there a name for the family of shapes/sets which follow these constraints for $k=1$ and $k=2$?

I can see that it'll be a superset of convex sets but can't find any specific names.

Comment: Bounded star-convex.

Comment: @max_zorn an annulus satisfies the properties specified by me but it's not star-convex

Comment: An annulus does not satisfy the stated conditions. Some lines cross the boundary four times, and others only twice.